# Soql using MAX query

Tags: apex, soql, aggregate

We are querying max value among certain field values of same data type from an object. we cant form perfect query . could anyone help to get perfect query.

Comment: It'd be easier to answer if you can share your current query and what output you'd like. Adding more details and context in your question will help us help you! :)

Comment: Oppty= [select MAAmount), AccountID from Opportunity where AccountID=:Acc.Id group By AccountID];                        HI this is the query we have used . Our scenario is to get the max value among the set of field's.

Answer (score 6):

I would look into Aggregate Results queries.  Without knowing too much about your requirements , here is a simple example below

```
list<aggregateResult> aggResults = [SELECT MAX(Amount)myMax FROM Opportunity];
System.debug('Max is: ' + aggResults[0].get('myMax'));
```

For more on AggregateResult queries, see the links below

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm

http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/04/12/using-aggregateresult-in-salesforce-com-soql/